# How to get the value of a formatted number

Tags: swift, formatting, numbers, int

I'm coding in Swift4. Is there a way to convert the formatted number to an Int? How to get the value of kinda this formatted number to do calculations?

`let formattedNumber = "12,345,678,910"
let newNumber = Int(formattedNumber)*2`

Comment: The proper solution is to use `NumberFormatter` to convert the string to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas first:

```
let number = formattedNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
let newNumber = Int(number)! * 2
```

Comment: Try to add check for `Int(number)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect.

```
extension String  {

  var intValue: Int   {

    let removedCharacter  = self.characters.map{String($0)}.filter{Int($0) != nil}.joined()
    print(removedCharacter)
    if !(removedCharacter.isEmpty)  {
        return Int(removedCharacter)!
    }
    return 0
  }

  func toInt(multiplyBy  : Int) -> String  {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
    let formattedString = formatter.string(for: intValue * multiplyBy)
    return formattedString!

  }
}

print("12,345,678,910".toInt(multiplyBy: 2))
>> 24,691,357,820
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't hardcode the grouping separator to `,` unless it is known that all of the strings to be parsed will always have commas. It all depends on how the original formatted string is being generated.